# Having a Counter issue on a PLD, programmed from NI MultiSim

Tags: multisim, programmable-logic

[image]In a PLD build:

I have built a counter that counts 0-9 combined to a second counter that counts to 8, to create a counter that counts up to 80.  It has a reset and hold (@80) function as well.  I have wired to a series of multiplexers so the 2 counters display on to 2 7 segment displays.  It works in MultiSim but on my protoboard the counter occasionally skips a number (typically around the 10's) e.g. 8 jumps to 10, 20 jumps to 22.  I was wondering what I am doing wrong.

When uploaded to the PLD, I remove the clock from input 22 and the interactive input from 23.  I am using slide switches to provide the signal.

I am a high school teacher and trying to work through issues before assigning to students.

Board is a Digilent mydigitalprotoboard
[image: Whole Circuit]

[image: 0-9 Counter]

[image: 0-8 Counter]

[image: Multiplexer&Outputs]

[NI Multisim 14 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18SJHr9GcXFBuoUnkSz1dHyLomIYY4a5_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: .ms14 is a NI Multisim file.

Comment: Your high school has invested in some very nice tools. Just documenting for the question. The small [PLTW S7](https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/pltw-s7/start) *stick* has a **Xilinx Spartan-7 FPGA** on it (the [XC7S25-1CSGA225C](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/903/ds180_7Series_Overview-1591537.pdf).) Here's the [reference manual](https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/pltw-s7/reference-manual). This may be the commercially available equivalent product: [CMOD S7](https://digilent.com/shop/cmod-s7-breadboardable-spartan-7-fpga-module/).

Comment: And here's the [myDigitalProtoboard for NI](https://digilent.com/shop/mydigital-protoboard-for-ni-mydaq-myrio/).

Answer (score 0):

The PLD will need a clock to debounce the switch inputs. The clock may be already available locally on the PLD plug-in board (the little rectangular board). Let's call it the global clock. Many PLDs have clock prescalers that divide it down (slow down the rate). Say a 50MHz global clock is fine, but the debounce counters will be fairly big. Much better to have it slowed down to something like 100kHz if possible.

The clock you use for the "user" logic should be separate from that. Let's call it the user clock. That comes from a slide switch.

Each switch input need two stages of processing before it's fed to the "user" logic.

1. Deglitching - synchronizes asynchronous input to global clock.
2. Debouncing - gets rid of mechanical artifacts.

**Deglitching**: Before the switch signal can be used to gate the counter, it must be deglitched by passing it through three (3) D flip-flops in series, clocked by the global clock. This ensures that at the output of those flip flops, the signal's transitions are synchronized to the global clock, and won't violate the setup/hold times of the counter's inputs.

**Debouncing**: There are many ways to do it, so here's one: Use an up-down counter that overflows in say 25ms. The counter has two inputs: UP and DOWN, and has a fixed global clock input that's always active. The UP and DOWN inputs gate the counting, i.e. enable it. Have it count up when the switch input is high, and count down when the switch input is low. Carry from the counter set an S-R latch. Borrow from the counter resets the S-R latch. Output of the S-R latch is the debounced version of the switch signal.

Note that counters often have an active-low borrow output. You'll want to check with whatever elements Multisim's schematic input supports.

Some PLD design input systems have built-in switch debouncing blocks. If one is available, just use it, and don't roll your own - although rolling your own is a nice learning exercise :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjXJgG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes in posting my question, and thanks for helping me fix them and the issue I was having.

Comment: @MarcusBernabo No worries. You're a teacher, you have your hands full already.